# How to check empty entry for Invar()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I want to store value in Intvar variable and when I click on submit if entry_var_get value is empty then it show error that value is empty , please help me about this

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as m_box



win = tk.Tk()

entry_var=tk.IntVar()
entry = tk.Entry(win , text='Enter the number', textvariable= entry_var)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
entry_var_get = entry_var.get()

def submit():
    if entry_var_get==None:
        m_box.showerror('error','empty value')

submit_btn = tk.Button(win , text='submit' , command=submit)
submit_btn.grid(row=1, column=0)


win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the value when the function `submit` is called instead of on first draw of the screen, this works for me.

Also you are treating the variable as an `int` this breaks if the user deletes the value from the box and hits `submit`.  A safer way is to use a `StringVar` and validate the input is as expected then convert it to type `int`.  As a general rule of thumb all user input should be validated as it's considered dangerous.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as m_box

win = tk.Tk()

entry_var = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(win, text='Enter the number', textvariable=entry_var)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0)


def submit():
    entry_var_get = entry_var.get()
    if entry_var_get.isdigit():
        entry_var_get = int(entry_var_get)
    if not entry_var_get or entry_var_get == 0:
        m_box.showerror('error', 'empty value')
    else:
        m_box.showinfo('success', f'value entered: {entry_var_get}')


submit_btn = tk.Button(win, text='submit', command=submit)
submit_btn.grid(row=1, column=0)

win.mainloop()
```